# Angled corners on CSS with Transparency

Tags: html, css

I've found multiple ways to create angled corners on an element, but what I'm trying to achieve is the ability to keep those corners while having transparency. I'm trying to keep this simple and purely in css (or less) and html.

A current working copy of what I have is below, this is obviously using white rotated boxes to overlap the edges causing the bevel.

Another way I noted was using linear gradients `linear-gradient(-220deg, transparent 10px, #ad1c1c 10px);` to affect a corner, this does allow the transparency through but I am just not capable of making a simplistic example with this applied to both top left and top right corners.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  background: #ad1c1c;
  color: #fff;
  font: bold 25px/35px 'Lucida sans';
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.bevel::before,
.bevel::after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.bevel::before {
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.bevel::after {
  right: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1 class="bevel">Test</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider multiple background to achieve this and you are almost good with your `linear-gradient(-220deg, transparent 10px, #ad1c1c 10px)`. Simply adjust the size and position:

```css
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(-225deg,transparent 10px,#ad1c1c 0) left /50.5% 100%,
    linear-gradient( 225deg,transparent 10px,#ad1c1c 0) right/50.5% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<h1 >Test</h1>
```

And with CSS variable to better control the size:

```css
h1 {
  --s:10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(-225deg,transparent var(--s),#ad1c1c 0) left /50.5% 100%,
    linear-gradient( 225deg,transparent var(--s),#ad1c1c 0) right/50.5% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<h1 >Test</h1>

<h1 style="--s:20px">Test</h1>


<h1 style="--s:30px">Test</h1>
```

Here is another idea considering skew and pseudo elements:

```css
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0 20px;
  background: #ad1c1c content-box;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:20px;
  background:#ad1c1c;
}
h1:before {
  right:0;
  transform-origin:left;
  transform:skewY(45deg);
}

h1:after {
  left:0;
  transform-origin:right;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="bevel">Test</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for the well-detailed answer with the alternate methods. I will accept it, but have some work to do to get this working now, specifically that I want the h1 to be the width of the text (inline-block) and be able to use colspan: all - this has more to do with inline-block failing me than your code. Thank you again!

Comment: @LimpingNinja you can easily change it to inline-block, simply make sure you add the needed padding for the corner so you won't have text overflow.

Comment: Hey there, the inline-block isn't the problem. I'm using this as a page header on a two-column setup in markdown, so if someone uses an # H1 header markdown it should span all columns. Unfortunately, for me, inline-block causes colspan:all to no longer works :( Thanks though, I'm still using this but not for the original case until I solve the other - I may open a new SO post if I don't find it out or if it isn't unfixable.